# Having a white flicker when hovering on images

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I followed a tutorial to change a background elementor column image when i hover on certain columns. This is the functional code i came up with ( "website" would be my website url), but there is a white flicker everytime everything seems to load... Any fix in mind?
Thank you

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('.littletravA').mouseenter(function() {
      $('#defaultB').css('background-image', 'url(website/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/0004_MENU_IMG_LTR_001.jpg)');
    });
    $('.littletravA').mouseleave(function() {
      $('#defaultB').css('background-image', 'url(website/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/0006_MENU_IMG_DEFAULT_001.jpg)');
    });
    $('.bestA').mouseenter(function() {
      $('#defaultB').css('background-image', 'url(website/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/0005_MENU_IMG_BB_001.jpg)');
    });
    $('.bestA').mouseleave(function() {
      $('#defaultB').css('background-image', 'url(website/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/0006_MENU_IMG_DEFAULT_001.jpg)');
    });
    $('.audreyA').mouseenter(function() {
      $('#defaultB').css('background-image', 'url(website/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/0000_MENU_IMG_AS_001.jpg)');
    });
    $('.audreyA').mouseleave(function() {
      $('#defaultB').css('background-image', 'url(website/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/0006_MENU_IMG_DEFAULT_001.jpg)');
    });
    $('.MLA').mouseenter(function() {
      $('#defaultB').css('background-image', 'url(website/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/0003_MENU_IMG_ML_001.jpg)');
    });
    $('.MLA').mouseleave(function() {
      $('#defaultB').css('background-image', 'url(website/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/0006_MENU_IMG_DEFAULT_001.jpg)');
    });
    $('.stribeA').mouseenter(function() {
      $('#defaultB').css('background-image', 'url(website/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/0001_MENU_IMG_STRIBE_001.jpg)');
    });
    $('.stribeA').mouseleave(function() {
      $('#defaultB').css('background-image', 'url(website/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/0006_MENU_IMG_DEFAULT_001.jpg)');
    });
    $('.aztecA').mouseenter(function() {
      $('#defaultB').css('background-image', 'url(website/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/0002_MENU_IMG_PYI_001.jpg)');
    });
    $('.aztecA').mouseleave(function() {
      $('#defaultB').css('background-image', 'url(website/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/0006_MENU_IMG_DEFAULT_001.jpg)');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#defaultB {
  background: #000000 transition: background 0.2s linear;
}
```

Comment: Smaller images? Maybe you should preload the images to the cache, that would make loading faster.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from making the images smaller

Can you perhaps also use DRY code  - something like this untested code

Note I gave the mouseover targets an ID

```js
const folder = 'https://via.placeholder.com/300x300?text='; // 'website/wp-content/uploads';
const def = '/2021/11/0006_MENU_IMG_DEFAULT_001.jpg';
const $defaultB = $("#defaultB");
const images = {
  "littletravA": "/2021/11/0004_MENU_IMG_LTR_001.jpg",
  "bestA": "/2021/11/0005_MENU_IMG_BB_001.jpg",
  "audreyA": "/2021/11/0000_MENU_IMG_AS_001.jpg",
  "MLA": "/2021/11/0003_MENU_IMG_ML_001.jpg",
  "stribeA": "/2021/11/0001_MENU_IMG_STRIBE_001.jpg",
  "aztecA": "/2021/11/0002_MENU_IMG_PYI_001.jpg"
}

$(function() {
  $(".upload").on({
    mouseenter: function() { 
      $("#defaultB").css("background-image", `url(${folder + images[this.id]})`);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $defaultB.css("background-image", `url(${folder + def})`);
    }
  });
});

document.getElementById("thumbs").innerHTML = Object
  .entries(images).map(([key, src]) => `<img class="upload" id="${key}" src="${folder+src}" />`)
  .join('')
```

```css
#defaultB {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-image : url(https://via.placeholder.com/300x300?text=/2021/11/0006_MENU_IMG_DEFAULT_001.jpg);
}

#thumbs img {
  height: 50px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="defaultB">Hello</div>
<div id="thumbs"></div>
```

Comment: that's really cool, could you give me more insights on what to change and how to put this in an html code block? thank you so much for your time and sorry for not knowing alot about coding

Comment: have a look at the update. I am not sure why we have a white blink - that is in principle not an improvement over your original question